# Using ASP.NET resource files from HTTP handler

Tags: asp.net, resources, httphandler

Is there any way how to get access to the resources stored in App_LoacalResource or App_GlobalResources? I familiar how to do that for web form page but can't figure out how to do that from .ashx files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some time of investigation I chose the next way:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> resAttrs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Resource.resx");

        foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
            resAttrs.Add(d.Key.ToString(), d.Value.ToString());
```

and then get access to resources through the `resAttrs` dictionary. Maybe it not the best way but that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject
```

or

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

Local Ressource

```
var result = GetLocalResourceObject("Name").ToString();
```

Global Ressource

You can try with `GetGlobalResourceObject` method

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/ms153593.aspx

Nota : GetLocalResourceObject is not available from the IHttpHandler (Viewed with Alex)

Comment: GetLocalResourceObject is not available from the IHttpHandler implementation.

Comment: Thank's Alex for your remark, i add to post